# New line in Silverlight's textblock

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight-4.0

I know that some will reply things such as `<LineBreak/>` this is not what I'm looking for.

I want to know if I store textblock's string in a resource file, can I do some thing about it to make the text in textblock to go to a new line.

tried `"&lt ; LineBreak/ &gt ;"` (w/o space),

tried `/r/n`

tried `&#13;&#10;`

None of the options worked, anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\r\n` should do the trick, I think you had the slashes the wrong way around. Even just `\n` should work.

In XAML the following works

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtMyText" Text="Hello&#10;World"/>
```

While in the code behind this works

```
txtMyText.Text = "Hello\nWorld";
```

For resources, you need to specify xml:space="preserve"

```
<system:String x:Key="message" xml:space="preserve">Hello&#10;World</system:String>
```

Using space preserve you can also do the following

```
<system:String x:Key="message" xml:space="preserve">Hello
World</system:String>
```

Note, there are no extra spaces because they would show up in the `TextBlock` because now all white space characters become significant.

Comment: did both way directly into xaml under text property

Comment: Confirmed not working. just did a test directly in my resource file

Comment: i put \r\nsss/r/nsdss, it show me exactly what I have keyed in

Comment: Yup, worked in both scenario, but if u use for example text="{StaticResource message}". In the app.xaml,<system:String x:Key="message">Hello&#13;World or Hello\nWorld </system:String>. \n will be shown literally,&#13; won't show though, and shows as if it is a empty space

Comment: @C_Rance: Maybe using a converter is the way forward for this solution.

Comment: @Ardman, thanks, browse through it, lazy to test it now as its midnight over at my side. So I presume for this case I will be using \r\n method as it is C#. But I still hope that can do something like what I intended. This will be my workaround if really still cant think of anything

Comment: @C_Rance, this works for resources as well, you need to specify space="preserve" see my edit.

Comment: I tested &#13; and it works for me, when set directly in the Xaml, but \n does not do it unless it is used in the code behind, which is exactly what @Chris Taylor says.  This is actually a problem I was having, too, and did not want to use <Linebreak/>.  Slick!

Comment: @Chris, woah, thanks man. anyway space="preserve" is totally xml right? mind telling me what are these type of keywords called?

Comment: @C_Rance: See the XML Specification section 2.10 White Space Handling, this is standard XML. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/

Comment: @Chris, once again thanks. actually I tot there were more xml: type of keywords that I do not know of.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried with SL5:

Open Resx file
Add a new string. Give it a name (Name column)
Enter any value you want (Value column).  If you need a linebreak just press SHIFT+ENTER.

In code behind,
MyTextBlock.Text=MyResource.MyItem;

Your textblock will correctly show your linebreaks.